# How to preserve mysql formatting when fetching data

Tags: python, mysql

I have `customer_price` stored as `DECIMAL (8,2)`.

Using Python, how would I preserve the two digits after the decimal?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT customer_price FROM table")
customer_price = cursor.fetchone() # this will give me values such as 7 instead of 7.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not imply Python is losing the number's digits after the decimal point. If you just need to print them with 2 decimal places then you should look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075128/python-print-all-floats-to-2-decimal-places-in-output). I.e.:

```
'%.2f' % your_number
```