# How to print out an answer in decimal using python?

Tags: python, string, output

I am attempting to solve a problem on Programmr that is: 
Make a simple numeric calculator. It should prompt the user for three numbers. Then add the numbers together and divide by 2. Display the result. Your program must support numbers with decimals and not just integers.

I have started the problem but if entering 1.1, 2.2, and 3.3, I get 3.3 when the answer is supposed to be 3.30. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, print all floats to 2 decimal places in output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075128/python-print-all-floats-to-2-decimal-places-in-output)

Comment: In all systems of arithmetic I'm familiar with, 3.3 = 3.30. So your code gives the correct answer.

Comment: @GregHewgill I think he want's a format specifier to the second place.

Comment: Are you sure you've stated the task correctly and interpreted the error correctly? As you've described it, 3.3 is correct output.

Comment: The website wants it specifically to be printed as 3.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to format your result to the second place, so just use the `.2f` format specifier to do this:

```
print '{:.2f}'.format(result) # print the float as a string to the second place value
```

Comment: x = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
y = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
z = float(input("Enter the third number: "))

result = float((x + y + z)/2.0)
print "{0:.2f}".format(result)

Comment: Whenever you have a `"{:...}".format(x)` pattern you can replace it with `format(x, "...")`

Comment: x = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
y = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
z = float(input("Enter the third number: "))

result = float((x + y + z)/2.0)
print format(result, ":/2f")

Comment: Are you on Python 3 or 2?

Comment: Then use parentheses: `print('{:.2f}'.format(result))`