# Showing the final zero with round()

Tags: python

For example, I'm trying to have the following return as `5.90`

```
test = round(5.9, 2)
print(test)
```

Comment: So after rounding up, you want your answer to have 2 decimal places?

Comment: What a float is and how you choose to format it when printing are two different questions which you are conflating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, print all floats to 2 decimal places in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075128/python-print-all-floats-to-2-decimal-places-in-output)

Comment: @JohnColeman Really bad leagacy Python 2 question dupe target. There probably exists a million good ones though.

Comment: @ruohola perhaps you could add a more recent answer to that question. I would happily upvote it. The answers to these questions tend to evolve over time, with newer answers often added.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'd rather not, since that question is explicitly asking about Python 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print float to n decimal places including trailing 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s)

Answer (score 2):

You can't control how many decimals floats have when you print them as is. To have control over that, you need to format the float into a string and then print that.

For example:
(Also: No point in rounding a number with 1 decimal point to the precision of 2 decimal points.)

```
test = 5.9 
print(f"{test:.2f}")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 5.90
> ```

You can read more about string formatting here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 0):

You can use %.2f instead.. for example:

```
    test = round(5.9, 2)
    print("%.2f"%test)
```

it will output 5.90.u can replace 2 with how many u wan to have numbers after decimal point

Answer (score -1):

this works for python2 and python3

```
n = 5.9
print('%.2f' % n)  # -> 5.90
```

in python3 also works

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(n))  # -> 5.90
```

and since python 3.7 also works:

```
print(f'{n:.2f}')  # -> 5.90
```